# Can't change UITextField Text

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield

```
-(void)histWordPushed:(NSString*)histword{
     self.word=histword;
    [self.searchWord setText:self.word];
    NSLog(@"search word %@",self.searchWord.text);
    NSLog(@"word %@",self.word);
}
```

In this code self.searchWord.text is null but self.word isn't. How can I set the text of the searchWord(`UITextField`)? Thanks.

Comment: Try using [self.searchWord setText:histword]; in place of [self.searchWord setText:self.word];

Comment: Do you create the UITextField programmatically or via Storyboards? If you are using Storyboards, did you bind your property to the control in the Storyboard (IBOutlet)?

Comment: You can check for 1). Correct Outlets 2). TextColor 3). Font size

Comment: I did check the outlets and created in storyboards. Text color and font size wont work. Because I'm testing it with NSLog.@Neha: it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked. I add this below code before `setText:`

```
self.searchWord = [ [ UITextField alloc ] init ];
```

Comment: This means you are creating a new UITextField. So what happened to the textfield you created using storyboard?

Comment: Yes I remove from storyboard and created it programaticaly. Then I changed my code again. Because I realized that the searchword value changed but I have to set every properties of UITextField to appear it. It isn't efficient.So I just remove settext from histWordPushed and put searchWord.text into viewDidAppear method. Should I edit my answer again, both of it works?